# Erro ao alterar charset usando MySQL Table Editor de latin1 para utf8

Tags: php, html, mysql, table, editor

Estou tentando alterar o charset, de uma tabela diretamente no banco usando MySQL Table Editor, de latin1 para utf8 porém, ao selecionar utf8 nas opções de charset ele muda automaticamente a collation para utf8mb4_general_ci e ao mandar aplicar as alterações me retorna seguinte erro:

```
collation para utf8mb4_general_ci is not valid for character set utf8
```

Dentre as dezenas de collations existentes na opção collation qual deve ser a correta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, a **correta** é aquela que lhe atente, então depende do caso qualquer uma pode ser essa tal correta que procura, agora se você esta querendo usar o padrão **ABNT2** então um *utf8 - default collation* irá resolver.

A respeito de mensagem de erro, pelo que parece já tens registros na tabela e esses registros não podem (não é válido) converter-los para o outro collation, uma forma simples de entender isso é se você já possui um caractere tipo **ç** e quer converte-lo para um formato americano onde ele não existe, então irá gerar um erro.

não pediu mas vou postar um exemplo codificado:

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`tabela` CHARACTER SET = utf8 ;
```

**Conforme comentários:**
arquivo php.ini

tem um trecho do código que deve estar comentado, ou se não existir escreva

```
; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Retire o caractere **;** que esta n inicio da linha *;default_charset = "UTF-8"* e reinicie o serviço do apache.

No arquivo http.conf também tem uma linha onde se faz uma configuração do charset:

```
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Mesmo esquema retire o primeiro caractere e faça um restart no serviço

Comment: certo, escolhi utf8_general_ci na collation. Foi aceito. Nas paginas coloquei meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" e nas paginas continua aparecendo � O que mais devo fazer?

Comment: altera as configurações do php.ini, da uma olhada lá

Comment: Só lembrando que saímos da **tag mysql** do enunciado estamos entrando em **html e php**

Comment: Rapaz!, são 1875 linhas de puro inglês, entendi bulufas, rs

Comment: rsrsr, só buscar pela palavra chave **charset** não tem muitas linhas sobre isso =D

Comment: 1: ; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"

Comment: 2:  ; Default charset for ibase_connect().
;ibase.default_charset =

Comment: 3: ; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.conf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: como se reinicia ou se  faz o restart? Não serve editar o arquivo e salvar?

Comment: Vai depender do caso, no windows vai no iniciar->executar e digite **services.msc** procure pelo apache na lista e clique no botão direito reiniciar precisa ser Administrador

Comment: se for linux, vai no shell e digite **service apache2 restart** precisa ser root

Comment: kkkkk, desculpe, tá falando grego comigo. Tá tudo lá no servidor.

Comment: sim é no servidor que faz essa configuração

Comment: vou lá ver isso